# How to find a particular class in BeautifulSoup using findAll

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, subprocess, python-requests

FindAll doesn't find the class I need. However I was able to find the class above that one, but the data structure is not that well organized.

- Do you know what can we do to get the data or organize the output from the class above which has all the data together ?

Please see the HTML below and the images.

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
my_url = 'https://www.vivino.com/explore?e=eJzLLbI11jNVy83MszU0UMtNrLA1MVBLrrQtLVYrsDVUK7ZNTlQrS7YtKSpNVSsviY4FioEpIwhlDKFMIJQ5VM4EAJCfGxQ='

#Opening a connection
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#html parse
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
container = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"wine-explorer__results__item"})
len(container)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you add the expected output to your question? What do you mean with 'organize the output'?

Comment: If you look a the page_soup, I see lots of markup like <div data-react-class="ExploreApplication" data-react-props="{&quot;e   which means the data you're looking for probably never rendered (js rendered), based on the nature of the request you made. You'll need to use a client that executes JS

Comment: ^ beautiful soup doesn't work with JavaScript, you need to use something like selenium

Comment: Thanks for advice, I will try next selenium,hopefully that will help to get the class needed.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters For instance to extract the review by item "<div class="statistics-item__content__value">4.5</div>"

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone, as you all suggested a module to read Javascript was needed to select that class. I've used selenium in this case, however PyQt5 might be a better option.

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver

my_url = 'https://www.vivino.com/explore?e=eJzLLbI11jNVy83MszU0UMtNrLA1MVBLrrQtLVYrsDVUK7ZNTlQrS7YtKSpNVSsviY4FioEpIwhlDKFMIJQ5VM4EAJCfGxQ='

#Opening a connection

#html parse

web_r = uReq(my_url)

driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(my_url)
page_soup = soup(web_r, "html.parser")
html = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")

#print(html)
html_page_soup = soup(html, "html.parser")
container = html_page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "wine-explorer__results__item"})
len(container)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dryscrape module with bs4 because wine-explorer selector is created by javascript. Dryscrape module helps you for javascript support.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following instead:

```
container = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "wine-explorer__results"})
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work since this class was created by javascript